WPF TabControl - Select tabs programatically one after another with delay
I need to select several tabs programatically with delay on button click. I looked through this answer, but it works only if I select a single tab without any extra code. In my case, I need to cycle through the tabs so user can see them in process:
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => tabControl.SelectedIndex = i % 3));

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

<TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
    <TabItem Header="TabItem1" />
    <TabItem Header="TabItem2" />
    <TabItem Header="TabItem3">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="button"
                    Content="Click"
                    Height="200"
                    Width="200"
                    Click="button_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>

However, the UI is blocked for the whole cycle and only the last tab is shown after the cycle is complete. How to solve the problem?

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = i % 3;

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

